# Dynamic column arrangement in bootstrap grid (bootstrap+vanilla js)

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, layout

I am creating a grid (so something with rows and columns with buttons in the cells) and a slider that should alter the number of columns.

The number of rows is virtually unlimited and, since the grid layout in bootstrap is implemented with a flexbox i should either swap column classes or redraw everything every onchange event.

is there another way in bootstrap or do i need to create a grid layout from scratch and alter the column layout each time?

Comment: it depends how much you master bootstrap or plain CSS/JS .Your question is vague, answers can only be opinion based somehow. What is your context, structure and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have a button that adds buttons in a grid container and they all have a certain column class with a certain size (col-*).

My first approach was to detect all the column tags in the container and change the class by popping in a new one replacing the old but that seems unfeasible (since i have to go trough each button),

The second approach was to redraw the whole grid and placing rows after the number of columns is reached which also seems pretty taxing on low end devices.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to do that by adding a counter of elements inside a row and whenever i reach the desired element number i append a new row and start adding elements to the last row

like so

```
   if(indexofrow%element.getColNumber()==0){
            indexofrow++;
            document.getElementById("canvas").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","<div class='row flex-nowrap'/></div>");
            drawSingleButton(i,element,arrayOfLayers);
        }else{
            drawSingleButton(i,element,arrayOfLayers);
            indexofrow++;
   }
```

it's probably a cheap workaround but for my case it works